# Media Query for mobile devices which will fit to all the screens

Tags: html, css

I am creating a mobile app, am using a media query:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Your Styles */
}
```

But the resolution is not fitting to the smaller screen devices.

In general for responsive UI, you should style for a dimension range. For e.g. any device with screen resolution less than 320x480 or something similar.

Is there any media query that supports for all the screen resolutions of mobile devices?

Comment: try max-device-width instead of max-width

Answer (score 1):

Full tutorial Here :
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/12/responsive-web-design-css3.html

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px}
#header
{
padding:20px;
overflow:auto;
}
#main
{
padding:10px;
}
#footer
{
padding:20px;
clear:both
}
#article,#sidebar
{
min-height:250px;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:auto
}

ul
{
list-style:none;
width:100%
}
li
{
padding:4px;
margin-bottom:5px;
background-color:#ffffcc;
text-align:center;
color:#00000
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){

ul
{
float:left;
}
li
{
float:left;
width:16%;
padding:4px;
margin-right:8px
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){

#article
{
float:left;
width:68%;
}
#sidebar
{
float:right;
width:30%;
}
#logo
{
float:left;
width:10%;
}
#nav
{
float:right;
width:80%;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {

#main
{
padding:20px 40px 20px 40px;
}

}
```

Comment: Modernizer is plugin used in tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with screen resolutions, more to do with media query support. Try a test like this:

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1px) {
   body {
    background: red;
   }
}
```

If that doesn't affect a browser, it [doesn't support media queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries). You can get javascript replacements to support older devices like [Respond.JS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: Then that means your phone doesn't support media queries. Include `<script src="https://raw.github.com/scottjehl/Respond/master/respond.min.js"></script>` and it should work

Comment: This is just for testing purposes, you shouldn't rely on github to host code you rely on, download a local copy and reference that.